# Pass Variables from Apache to JBoss?

Tags: apache, jboss, saml, mod-jk, shibboleth

I've been requested to get an old JBoss application working with Shibboleth.

The server already has Shibboleth set up. When you attempt to access the JBoss application, you're taken to a Shibboleth login screen (if you haven't already logged in with it). Then you're taken to the old JBoss application's login screen.

I want the JBoss application to, instead of presenting a login screen, to just get some variables (possibly from request headers) to determine which user has logged in.

I found this article over here about getting Shibboleth to work with Tomcat:
https://www.commandprompt.com/blog/real-world_example_of_adding_saml_authentication_to_a_jboss_application/

About 2/3 of the way through that page they have this section:

> **ACCESSING AUTHENTICATION INFORMATION IN THE APPLICATION**
>
> Shibboleth passes the authentication information to the web application in form of CGI environment variables (`$_SERVER` array variable in PHP.) The sign of an established SAML session is presence of `Shib-Session-ID` environment variable.
>
> However, if you use JBoss application server your code lives in a different process and has no direct access to the Apache server environment. To pass the required variables from Apache to JBoss you'll need to add the following mod_jk configuration directive:
>
> `JkEnvVar Shib-Session-ID`
>
> After that, you may get the value of this variable using `request.getAttribute("Shib-Session-ID")` in your Java or JSP code.

`mod_jk` isn't part of my Apache installation, though. Do I need to install it, or is there another directive which is part of a standard Apache installation that I can use instead?

Comment: This is not necessarily associated with Shibboleth, see the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424142/how-can-i-read-apache-httpd-env-variables-from-a-java-application-running-in-tom , they probably cover your use case too

Comment: @YiannisKakavas - Perfect! Thank you - it turns out Apache has `mod_proxy_ajp`, so it was automatically passing AJP variables through.